# How to set an environment variable in AWS MWAA

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

I'm trying to set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable in MWAA to authenticate Google Cloud, but I can't figure out how.

In GCP Composer I can just use the console and add an environment variable, is there nothing like that in AWS MWAA?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom environment variable like in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/configuring-env-variables.html#configuring-env-variables-customizing)

Or you store google cloud creds in the connection manager.